# split on regex using lookahead

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to use regex to split this string

`\r\r\nabc:\r\r\n\tdef ghi:\t\tS-1-5-18\r\r\n\tlll zzz:\t\tstring1\r\r\n\t`

into

`abc:\r\r\n\t
def ghi:\t\tS-1-5-18\r\r\n\t
tlll zzz:\t\tstring1\r\r\n\t`

However, my current regex using lookahead only seem to be able to match this string

`nabc:\r\r\n\tdef gh`

regex : `\w+:[\w\\n\\r \\t]+(?=[\\t]+[\w]+:)`

I am using https://regex101.com to evaluate on this string.

Can i know what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Using this in python throws up a `unbalanced paranthesis exception`

```
re.split('(?<!\\)[\w\s]+\:[\w\\\s\-]+\\t', string_to_split)
```

Comment: What is the delimiter here?

Comment: what language ?

Comment: i am using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<!\\)[\w\s]+\:[\w\\\s\-]+\\t
```

this one can match all of 3 string

Comment: Nice, if `\t` isnt the delimiter then you could expand it to be `(?<!\\)[\w\s]+.*?(?=(?<!\\)[\w\s]+\:|$)` using a positive lookahead to search for either end of line or the start of the regex again.

Comment: what does ?< mean

Comment: (?<!...)
Ensures that the given pattern would not match and end at the current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does not consume characters.

Comment: @yudongshen hi i tried it in python it says unbalanced parantehsis

Comment: use match instead of split